# Sample rate vs noise floor in power spectral density measurement

Tags: python, sampling, power-spectral-density

I am trying to measure the noise floor of my picoscope. I want to generate a PSD in volts per root hz that I can compare with specs from other equipment, e.g. a preamp. I gathered some data from my scope with the input shorted, and then created a PSD using scipy.signal.welch in python. However, I noticed that if I changed the sample rate of the measurement, the noise floor changed. This is not good because what I want is an absolute measurement.

I determined that this behavior is due to welch, not the scope itself, by repeating the phenomenon with random data, like so:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

mean = 0
std = 1 
num_samples = 600000
seg = 20000
perFast = 48E-9
perSlow = 480E-9

samples = np.random.normal(mean, std, size=num_samples)

secsFast = [x*perFast for x in range(0,num_samples)]
secsSlow = [x*perSlow for x in range(0,num_samples)]
secs = []
secs.append(secsFast)
secs.append(secsSlow)

labels = ['fast sample rate','slow sample rate']
  
plt.figure(figsize=(9,6), dpi= 100).patch.set_alpha(1)

for i, sec in enumerate(secs):

    npVolts = np.array(samples)
    t = np.array(sec)

    fs = 1/np.abs((t[1]-t[0])) #calc sample rate

    #calculate fft
    freq, psd = signal.welch(npVolts, fs=fs, nperseg=seg, window='boxcar')

    plt.semilogx(freq, np.sqrt(psd), alpha=0.5, label=labels[i])

plt.ylabel('V/√Hz')
plt.xlabel('Hz')
plt.grid()
plt.title('Welch of White Noise at Different Sample Rates')
plt.legend()

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=0.8)
ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.5)

plt.ylim(1E-4,1E-2)
```

Output:
[image: welch PSD of noise at different sample rates]

Clearly this is expected behavior and I am confused. How do I make a PSD of my data with a noise floor that doesn't depend on sample rate -- like what I would get if I used a spectral analyzer?

Comment: Since Welch's method essentially averages the different sections it is probably not well suited for determining the noise floor (for example changing the value of seg should also have an impact on the results).

Comment: I don't think that's correct. When measuring noise floors with a spectral analyzer, you often average multiple PSDs. You shouldn't average the time series when measuring a noise floor, but that's not what Welch does.